# How to pull specific element from list to compare grades?

Tags: python, oop

I wrote this code to compute student quiz scores and I got this part to work.

```
class Student :
    Scores = {} 
  
    # initializing the constructor method
    def __init__(self, name, grade) : 
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        
    def getScores(self) :
        # begin function to obtain scores # 
        answer_key = []
        # read into answer_key list, the answer key from file
        answer_key = [line.strip() for line in open("answers.txt", 'r')]

        student_answers = []
        # read into student_answers list, student answers from file
        student_answers = \
            [line.strip().split(',') for line in open("data.txt", 'r')]
        total_score = 100
        '''
        '''
        # place additional code statements here for the above function 

        #---start your loop processing logic here---#
        for outerIndex in range(len(student_answers)) :
            #check the name on the file with the object’s name
            if student_answers[outerIndex][0] == self.getName() :
                for innerIndex in range(len(answer_key)) :
                    if answer_key[innerIndex] != student_answers[outerIndex][innerIndex + 1] :
                        total_score -= 10

        #---end your loop processing logic here---# 

        #---continue the class definition#

        
        Student.Scores[self.getName()] = total_score;
        # end function to obtain scores #
                
    def getName(self) :
        return self.name; 

    @staticmethod
    def sortDict() :
        return sorted(Student.Scores.items());

    #---end the class definition#                 

# declare a class object #                 

student_objs = [
   Student("Sammy Student",65),
   Student("Betty Sanchez", 45),
   Student("Alice Brown", 100),
   Student("Tom Schulz", 50),
   Student("Clark Kent", 100)
   ]

for index in range(len(student_objs)) :
    student_objs[index].getScores();

sortList = Student.sortDict();
 
for k, v in sortList :
    print (k, "has score:", v)
print()
```

From this list, I need to pull the scores from each student and compare them to their quiz scores:

```
student_objs = [
   Student("Sammy Student",65),
   Student("Betty Sanchez", 45),
   Student("Alice Brown", 100),
   Student("Tom Schulz", 50),
   Student("Clark Kent", 100)
   ]
```

This is what I came up with, but it did not work. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong:

```
for k, v,  in sortList :
    print(k, ":", student_objs[index].grade, ",", v)
```

It gave me this output:

```
Alice Brown has score: 90
Betty Sanchez has score: 90
Clark Kent has score: 100
Sammy Student has score: 80
Tom Schulz has score: 100

Alice Brown : 100 , 90
Betty Sanchez : 100 , 90
Clark Kent : 100 , 100
Sammy Student : 100 , 80
Tom Schulz : 100 , 100
```

What do I need to do to fix my code? I need the output to look like this:

```
Alice Brown has score: 90
Betty Sanchez has score: 90
Clark Kent has score: 100
Sammy Student has score: 80
Tom Schulz has score: 100

Alice Brown : 100 , 90
Betty Sanchez : 45 , 90
Clark Kent : 100 , 100
Sammy Student : 65 , 80
Tom Schulz : 50 , 100
```

Comment: What is your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `index` is leftover from your previous while loop.  Your data structure is really not conducive to what you want to do.  The `total_score` should be stored in each Student object, not salted away in a dictionary that is global to the class.  Your sorted list is just the name and the final grade.  The best you can do write now is to scan through the `student_objs` list by hand, looking for the object that matches the name you want.

```
for k, v in sortList:
    for student in student_objs:
        if student.name == k:
            print(k, ":", student.grade, ",", v)
```

Alternatively, if you didn't care about sorted order:

```
for s in student_objs:
    print( s.name, ":", s.grade, ",", sortList[s.name] )
```